# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS login loop

Tags: 12.04, boot

I'm asking this because initially, my problem was a power failure during installation

so I typed the following instructions in the maintenance shell:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /
 sudo dpkg --configure a
 sudo mount -o remount,ro /
 sudo sync
 sudo reboot
```

The first three lines worked, afterwards, my computer (a Dell Inspiron 530) got stalled 
for several hours, so I unplugged it. When I turned it on, the log in screen appeared, and after I try to write my password, it leads me back to the log screen. 
I must note that when I typed the first three lines during the maintenance shell mode, it said that the errors which were encountered during processing were:

```
initscripts
bluez
gnome-bluetooth
```

Also, I must add that I've tried other solutions I've found, such as changing the .Xauthority file  and when I type that it says:

```
`W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock`
```

So, what should I do to get rid of this issue? It's driving me crazy. Also, if it can't be fixed, then what should I do to reinstall Ubuntu without losing my /Home files?

---

I've tried the abovementioned instructions and still it doesn't work. It marks certain problems with bluez and gnome-bluetooth. Above are the screens:

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2I83.jpg)

[second screen](http://postimg.org/image/lj20tvzi1/full/)

Comment: Is Ctrl+Alt+F1 what you're looking for?

Comment: Also, if you can get into the terminal, try running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. If it claims it's already installed, just remove it and install it again (won't cause any harm).

Comment: If it sends you back to the login screen, your home directory could not be written to. Is root still mounted as `ro`? Is your disk full?

Comment: No, my disk isn't full. Root appears as root@username-Inspiron-530.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you meant that the power failure happened during upgrades, not during a new installation.

Try the following.

1. Go into recovery mode.
2. `mount --options remount,rw /`
3. `mount --all`
4. `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install`
5. `sudo dpkg --configure --pending`

Reboot, log in and open a terminal. (If you can't log in, reboot to recovery mode with networking, repeating steps 2 and 3 above.)

1. `sudo apt-get update`
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Let us know if this works.

Comment: I edited my main entry, adding some screens about the commands you suggested, Paddy. They didn't work out entirely, unfortunately.

Comment: @Narida I don't see any screens about those commands. Did you try all of the commands, in the correct order? If they didn't work, we need to know exactly what happened.

Comment: I finally added the screens correctly. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: OK, @Narida. Did you try the commands that I gave you? What happened when you did?

Comment: See 'first screen' and 'second screen' at the first post. It didn't react correctly.

Comment: OK, @Narida. Your second screen shows the prompt (`root@adria-Inspiron-530s:~#`). That's where you start entering the commands that I gave you. I don't know if they'll work, but please try.

Comment: I tried it.  

And now the login screen appears but when I write my passwords it still gets stuck on a loop. It happens the same even with 'Guest Session'.

(btw i was unable to reply during these past months due to an illness)

Comment: Also when I try to register my password it says 'having multiple values in <test> isn't supported and may not work as expected'

Comment: @Narida, I need to be very clear: Did you run *each* command, *in order*? Did *every* command finish successfully? You might want to repeat the process in case something was left over.

Comment: I did it. Just after writing `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` nothing was upgraded nor installed and it said:

`Setting up bluez (4.101 0ubuntu13) ...
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory.
reload: Unknown instance:
invoke-rc.d: initscript dbus, action "force-reload" failed.
runlevel:/var/run/utmp: No such file or directory.
start: Job failed to start.
invoke-rc.d: initscript bluetooth, action "Start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package bluez (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1`

...

Comment: `dpkg: error processing package gnome-bluetooth (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
   Errors were encountered while processing:
  bluez
  gnome-bluetooth
E: Subprocess /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: Narida, sorry about your illness; I hope that you are getting better. You have been having this computer problem for a long time. I think that your easiest way forward is to boot with a Live CD, back up all your data onto external storage, reinstall Ubuntu from scratch, and restore your data. I know that this is not what you want to hear, but it's what I would do. I'm sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: So, if  I boot through a Live CD, how I'm able to see/retrieve all my files?

Comment: Also, I was checking similar cases as mine through StackExchange and in one it was suggested to switch to VT (Cntrl+Alt+F1/6), and stop LightDM.
I managed to do the first one, and the interesting thing is that it points out that my flaw lies in this:
`*¨Starting SMB/CIFS File and Active Directory Server    [fail]`

Comment: @Narida, when you boot from a Live CD (or Live USB), you will start up in a "temporary" Ubuntu. If you open Files (a.k.a. Nautilus), you will see your hard drives listed on the left-hand side. Simply click whichever one you want in order to view it. You can copy files from there onto an external USB drive. If your home folder is on a separate partition, you can reinstall Ubuntu without overwriting your data; but, as this is susceptible to human error, back your data first anyway. (This all assumes that you had not used encryption in your home folder.)